# JQuery Animate Function Not Changing Left Absolute Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

**SECOND EDIT:**
Ok so I have certainly had some help here on this problem, however when I now enter the working model into a class structure in my page is breaks and can't find method. I tried caching the "this" in order to see my methods however I am having no luck...

New JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/goredefex/3QvP9/22/

Also, I am aware the JS Fiddle doesn't work with classes because when I inspect it I can see that it auto adds a $(function() {}); load event without my control.

**New JS Code** (all other code exact same):

```
$(function() {                              
    var m = new ImgMarquee("#box");
});

function ImgMarquee(container) {
    this.setUpImages(container);
    var total = this.findAndSetContWidth(container);

    //Make Second Hidden Stage
    var doppelganger = $(container).clone();                
    $(container).first().append(doppelganger.html()); //<-- Add In Stage

    this.animateMarquee(this.animateMarquee, container, total);

} //EOC

//Calculates Width & Sets Viewer
ImgMarquee.prototype.findAndSetContWidth = function(container) {
    //Set Parameters
    var imgs = $(container + " a img"),
        width = 0;
    //Calculate Width
    $(String(container)).find(imgs).each(function() {
        width += $(this).width();
    });
    //Set Container Width
    $(container).css({"width":String(width*2)});

    return width;

}; //end function

//Adjusts Height Of Images To Parent Container
ImgMarquee.prototype.setUpImages = function(container) {
    var imgs = $(container + " a img"), 
        gutter = 3;
    //Attach To All Given Images
    $(String(container)).find(imgs).each(function() {
        $(this).css({
            "max-height":String($(this).parent().parent().height())+"px",
            "padding-right":String(gutter)
        });
    });

}; //end function

//Adds JQuery Animation To Container
ImgMarquee.prototype.animateMarquee = function(recursion, c, t) {
    $(c).animate({'margin-left':String(-(t))}, 
        {
            easing:'linear',
            duration:50000,
            complete: function() {
                $(c).css({"margin-left":"0"});
                this.animateMarquee(this.animateMarquee, c, t);
            }
         }
    );
}; //end function
```

**THIS IS THE ORIGINAL QUESTION:**
Haven't come across the answer to this yet and I am wondering what I have done wrong. I have an animate function to make a silly image marquee scroller and the only part I can't get right is the part where an image drops off the visible x-axis on the DOM `(x < 0px)` and moves itself back to the front of the line at the top of the right-most x-axis.

In other words, it gets moved behind the scenes to being back on the right side hidden awaiting to come into the staging where the user can see it.

Just a simple infinite scroller is all I want that continiously and slowly shows all the images in my set.

**FIRST EDIT - NOW OLD:** Added JS-Fiddle as requested [here]:http://jsfiddle.net/goredefex/3QvP9/

Here's my code....

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="backing">
        <div id="box">
            <img class="img" src="img/x.png" />
            <img class="img" src="img/y.png" />
            <img class="img" src="img/z.png" />
            <img class="img" src="img/1.png" />
            <img class="img" src="img/2.png" />
            <img class="img" src="img/3.png" />
            <img class="img" src="img/x.png" />
            <img class="img" src="img/y.png" />
            <img class="img" src="img/z.png" />
            <img class="img" src="img/1.png" />
            <img class="img" src="img/2.png" />
            <img class="img" src="img/3.png" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <button id="btn">GO!</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
        #backing{
            height: 55px;
            width: 800px;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            position: relative;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        #box{
            height: 55px;
            width: 3000px;
            position: absolute;
        }

        #box img {
            float: left;
            opacity: .6;
        }

        #box img:hover {
            opacity: 1;
        }
```

**JS:**

```
    $(function() {                              
        $("#btn").on("click", function() {                  

                var total = setMarqueeAndSum(".img");                   

                //Animation
                launchMarquee(total, ".img");

            });
        });

        function setMarqueeAndSum(iClass) {
            //Keep Track of Positions
            var lPos = 0, 
                gutter = 3;
            //Attach To All Given Images
            $(String(iClass)).each(function() {
                $(this).css({
                    "max-height":String($(this).parent().height())+"px",
                    "position":"absolute", 
                    "top":"0px", 
                    "left":function() {
                        return lPos==0 ? "0px":String(lPos + gutter) + "px";
                    }
                });
                lPos = lPos + $(this).width() + gutter;
            });

            return lPos;

        } //end function

        function launchMarquee(t, iClass) {
            $(iClass).animate({left:'-='+String(t)+'px'}, 
                {
                    easing:'linear',
                    duration:40000,
                    step:function(now, fx) {
                        var cache = t;
                        if($(this).position().left<(0-$(this).width()))
                            $(this).css({"left":String(cache)+"px"});
                    },
                    complete: function() {launchMarquee(t);}
                 }
            );
        } //end function
```

Comment: a JSFiddle would be great..

Comment: added a fiddle for you

Comment: At which point do you want it to stop, and start moving to the other side?

Comment: I dont need it to stop. Well unless it has to. I just want the whole banner to be a constant, slow moving image banner that shows all the logo's of the companies I am supporting on my page. So when a logo goes off the left side and becomes hidden I want it to actually be moved instantly off to the right hand side and be prepared to loop back in so the user never sees anything but an infinite logo marquee thats always got the same logos going around and around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are always many ways to do these things, but here's what came to my mind first:

1. Duplicate the images.
2. Animate them halfway (they're just for illusion of infinity).
3. Roll back the animation instantly by setting appropriate css (margin-left: 0).
4. Repeat the steps.

   ```
   $(function() {                              
   $("#btn").on("click", function() {                  

       $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled"); // Disable the button after click

       var $box  = $("#box"),
           total = 0;

       // Make box width equal to imgs summed up (not wider than that)
       $box.find("img").each(function(){
           total += $(this).width();
       });
       $box.css("width", total);
       console.log("The '.box' width is ", total);

       setImgs($box); // Set css propertes of an image here

       var $box_copy = $box.clone(); // Copy the imgs...
       $("#box").first().append($box_copy.html()); // ... and append them (basically duplicate all images)

       animate(animate, $box, total);
   });

   function setImgs(parent) {
       parent.find("img").each(function()
       {
           $(this).css({ 
               "max-height": "50px",
           });
       });
   }

   function animate(callback, $box, total)
   {
       $box.animate({
           "margin-left" : -total / 2
       }, 10000, "linear", function(){
           $box.css("margin-left", "0"); // Roll back the animation instanly by setting margin to 0
           animate(animate, $box, total); // Then animate again...
       });
   }
   });
   ```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3QvP9/16/

IMPORTANT TIP: Don't animate every image at the same time, jus animate their container. Save the planet, don't kill browsers.

Comment: okay I it took forever but I tried everything and it works much better. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok I spoke too soon. Its kinda messed up. Heres current fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/goredefex/3QvP9/17/ ... It has a messed up doubling vertically and it doesn't clone at the right time. I have tried changing many things but nothing seems to stop the end from showing before it copies. Also in my chrome browser the whole thing restarts, and blinks visibly, the clone doesn't add to the end at all it just restarts the whole animation over. In the fiddle somehow it doesn't

Comment: The mistake is that first, you measure total width of the container, then you duplicate its content... After doubling content, you should do the same with the container width.

Just change line 31 to `$(c).css({"width":String(width*2)});` and it shall work.

Also, you don't need to divide the 't' variable in line 51, since you measured the 't' before duplicating content.

Comment: I honestly CAN'T thank you enough for your help because it now works! However, I don't just need code I need the understanding of it so I have to ask. I followed your code step by step so my code is very similar in progression, so how come your fiddle didn't need those alterations? I am looking at it now and it looks the exact same to me. The only thing I did in a different order was to change my individual image heights...

Comment: The truth is that I have made a mistake. I calculated the `total` before adjusting widths and heights of images. As a result, `total` was quite a big number - big enaugh to fit duplicated content, and at the same time not big enaugh to notice the mistake it the animation - PURE COINCIDENCE haha. Here's fixed code: http://jsfiddle.net/3QvP9/20/

Comment: Thank you so much Jakrub I appreciate the help!!! I am learning a lot here but when I went to implement it into my website with a class structure it breaks for some reason. It does about 4-6 loops depending (on what? I have no idea) and then it says that animateMarquee does not exist. Heres a new fiddle... jsfiddle.net/goredefex/3QvP9/22/   ..... apparently it also doesn't like class structures in fiddle lol. It auto adds the $(window).load function

Comment: You're doing it wrong...

1. Adding methods to a prototype only makes sense when you initiate the mother object many times (it's related to memory). You are only doing it once... `new ImgMarque()`

2. You're passing strings as arguments, then binding jQuery objects inside methods. Don't do that. Instead, pass objects (look at my fiddle).

I rewrote the fiddle the way it should be, but it it is my last comment.

http://jsfiddle.net/3QvP9/36/

Good luck!

Comment: I am using this object many times and in many projects over time. I need an instantiable object. Thanks I found my problem it was just in the caching and when I was doing it.